# Is there a way to reproduce "RkCard" without using the component?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

Ever since I've used `npm install`, it's been error after error. Something in RkCard is not letting use it in FlatList...

```
<FlatList

       data={ this.state.combinedArray }


       renderItem = {({item}) =>
       <RkCard style={{width:'80%', alignSelf:'center', marginBottom: 100, backgroundColor:'#f5f5f5', borderRadius: 20}}>
       
       </RkCard>

     }

      keyExtractor={item => item.id}
       removeClippedSubviews


      />
```

Comment: Whats the RkCard component ?, if you replace it with a View does it work ?

Comment: RkCard is a customized div basically. It's a bootstrap type of thing. My flatlist is inside the View tag

Comment: renderItem = {({item}) =>
       <View style={{width:'80%', alignSelf:'center', marginBottom: 100, backgroundColor:'#f5f5f5', borderRadius: 20}}>
       
       </View>

     } check whether this works ? then the issue is with rkcard

Comment: Yup that was problem, thanks. Now I just have to figure out how to reproduce the styling of RkCard

Comment: If you could update the question with code for Rkcard i can check it :)

Comment: Ok I updated the question (not exactly sure how to word it though)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217611/discussion-between-guruparan-giritharan-and-laney-williams).